# How to get values from XML programmatically? - Android

Tags: android, xml

First, I did do my research, but couldn't find any.

I know this may seem like a trivial question, but how exactly do you retrieve values from an XML file (in my case, a layout XML)

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above example, I would like to get the value of "padding". How would I do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not "get values from XML". Rather, you *inflate* a view from XML, and then you can query the state of the view, which will have it's state be what was declared in XML.

In your case:

First, you need to give your view an id so you can refer to it in code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_for_this_view_here"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

Next you find this view by that ID in your Activity or Fragment after you've inflated the view from XML. For example, if you were in an Activity that had set this layout as the content, you can find the view like so:

```
setContentView(R.layout.id_for_the_layout_file);
LinearLayout yourView = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.id_for_this_view_here);
```

Finally, once you have the view reference, you can query it's state. In this case, for example, if you want to know the padding, use [getPaddingLeft()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getPaddingLeft()) and / or any of the other "getPadding" methods.

```
int leftPadding = yourView.getPaddingLeft();
```

Hope the helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Get its own attributes programmatically:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
int p = linearLayout.getPaddingTop();
int b = linearLayout.getGravity();
//...
```

> Get its relative position with its layout container:

Example, your linear layout is in a ConstrainLayout:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
int t = layoutParams.topMargin;
int b = layoutParams.leftMargin;
//...
```